# How to add a php parameter to a url?

Tags: php, html

I got to add a parameter such as $this->rock['link']; in a url.

```
<a href="<? "http://iguang.tw/?from=service&mail=$this->mail['link']?>">
```

It didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question misses too many details, but the task is trivial anyway. Try:

```
<a href="<?php echo "http://iguang.tw/?from=service&mail={$this->mail['link']}"?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://iguang.tw/?from=service&mail=<?php echo $this->mail['link'];?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you need to echo the php var

```
<a href="http://iguang.tw/?from=service&mail=<? Php echo $this->mail['link']?>">link </a>
```